# How do I navigate back to listings

Tags: php, html, navigation, breadcrumbs

I have built a business directory with the following structure:

[image]

As you can see there are 4 different paths that can be taken to reach a business profile.

I would like to build a breadcrumb with html and php (no jquery) and be able to navigate from the business profile, business gallery and individual image page back to the listings page I came from.

Which function in php would I use to remember where I came from? Would I carry the url for the listings page through as a variable to the other pages? If so would I use a session?

Comment: Session or Cookies should help; and yes, I think storing the URLs is a necessity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is the one you need

this tells you from what url a visitor arrives into a page

SESSIONS and COOKIES can pass this variable across other pages

As DaGhostman Dimitrov mentioned, this variable can be empty if user surfs privatley or with plugins that block traking or by using bookmarks

Comment: but may be an empty variable (if user uses DoNotTrack extension or some and or in privacy mode). I have used it an some times it was empty .. not very reliable. But +1 cuz it is an option!

Comment: @DaGhostman Dimitrov  true - it will also be empty if target url comes from bookmark

Comment: I suppose if the variable is empty I could just change it to a start new search button to cover all bases so thanks andrew I will give it a go.

Comment: @Richard Bell If variable is empty, you can set a default page, such as "Listings by name" - that's what i do in such scenarios

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take:

1. Get breadcrumbs (array) from Session.
2. Get current URL.
3. Append current URL in the breadcrumbs array.
4. Update breadcrumbs in Session.

Repeat the steps for each page load.

Comment: Thanks for your input Amir. andrew has given me the function I was looking for.